# Check duplicate value in localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to check if a id exist in database it will just simply replace it. When i try to do that it is adding the same id.

```
addEntry = (e,id) => {
  e.preventDefault()
    
  let product_list = []
  let productCost = document.getElementById('projectcost').value;
  let productQty = document.getElementById('productQty'+id).value;
  let productId = id;
    
  if(localStorage.getItem('myItems')){
    product_list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myItems'))
    product_list.push({productId,productCost,productQty})
    localStorage.setItem('myItems',JSON.stringify(product_list))
  } else {
    product_list.push({productId,productCost,productQty})
    localStorage.setItem('myItems', JSON.stringify([{productId, productCost, productQty}]))
  }
}
```

Output

```
[{"productId":44,"productName":"Cleansing milk with Toner","productCost":"140","productQty":"1"},{"productId":44,"productName":"Cleansing milk with Toner","productCost":"280","productQty":"2"},{"productId":44,"productName":"Cleansing milk with Toner","productCost":"420","productQty":"3"}]
```

output I want

```
[{"productId":44,"productName":"Cleansing milk with Toner","productCost":"280","productQty":"2"},{"productId":43,"productName":"Hair Spa 100 gm","productCost":"160","productQty":"1"}]
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code (other than maybe the getElementByIds not having a unique identifier). The problem of the same ID being added is coming from your other code that is calling addEntry. Please share the rest of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to check if the product is already located
in `localStorage` if so get it index and replace it and if not just append it to the `product_list`

try this

```
let product_list = []
  let productCost = document.getElementById('projectcost').value;
  let productQty = document.getElementById('productQty'+id).value;
  let productId = id;

  if(localStorage.getItem('myItems')){
    product_list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myItems'))
    const DuplicatedIndex = product_list.findIndex(product => product.productId == productId)

if(DuplicatedIndex == -1) {
   product_list.push({productId,productCost,productQty})
} else {
  product_list[DuplicatedIndex] = {productId,productCost,productQty}
}
localStorage.setItem('myItems',JSON.stringify(product_list))

   }else{
   
    product_list.push({productId,productCost,productQty})
    localStorage.setItem('myItems',JSON.stringify([{productId,productCost,productQty}]))
   }
}
```

Comment: @StephenOstermiller thanks for your comment, I will consider this in the future

Answer (score 2):

Before pushing the new item into `product_list`, you should check if that list has the item whose `productId` equals to `productId` and then replace it with the new item or just push that item.
I will put the correct code below:

```
const index = product_list.findIndex(item => item.productId === productId);
if(index === -1) {
    product_list.push({productId,productCost,productQty});
} else {
    product_list[index] = {productId,productCost,productQty};
}
```